# How do I know what Youtube video linked to my site and is driving lots of traffic from Youtube's home page?

Tags: google-analytics, youtube

I'm getting a lot of visits on the homepage from YouTube (according to GA), but can't seem to find out where from.

Is there any way to find out who linked to my site? I checked with Ahrefs, Google Console, and even referral path in GA.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube doesn't provide a referral path. As a result, it looks like the referrals are coming from YouTube's home page instead of the actual video page. Assuming these are your videos, you have a couple of ways to figure this out...

1. You can look at the landing pages for people who came to your website from YouTube. The easiest way to access this in Google Analytics is to go to Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Referrals -> click on YouTube -> add a secondary dimension of "Landing Page." From here, you can work backward to determine which landing pages you've linked to from which video. If you've linked to the same landing page from multiple videos, this won't give you a perfect answer but at least somewhat closer.
2. The other option is you can add UTM tracking parameters to the links you share on YouTube. You can build those out using this tool https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/ (you can also copy as a short link to make this a bit easier to share).  With UTMs, you could put the video name you are linking from in the Campaign Name field. Then, you can view this in Google Analytics (Campaign Name is under the Secondary Dimension of Campaign).

Comment: They're not my videos. Someone else added a link of my site in their video description, I assume.

Comment: @PunctUlica I see - so, in that case, option 1 should help to at least understand the landing page being linked to. You could then search Google narrowed to YouTube's site for that specific page in quotes. For example, if I saw my company's home page as a landing page from YouTube, I could search this on Google to see which videos come up...
site:youtube.com "https://www.elementive.com"

Comment: The site:youtube.com search didn't work either. I'm guessing that who linked to the site used a different anchor.